# I can't find my content layers in my web scene on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, web-scene

I am new on ArcGIS Online. I started uploading geographic layers; in my webmap I can load them when I search for layers in my contents, like shown below
[image]

But in my webscene I can't find any layers?

[image]

Comment: I believe your uploads are not scenes so they will not appear

Comment: I uploaded Geojson & shp zipped files

Comment: Those layer types are not not supported in the Scene Viewer. You will need to publish those as feature layers (hosted or coming from enterprise feature services). https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/add-layers-to-scene.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_AE4815736AC64DF09958DF8E73397485

Comment: What are the files extensions of 3d features supported in the Scene Viewer?

Comment: You can publish your own 3D point symbols to online and use those symbols on point features coming from feature layers and scene layers. For other 3D layers we have 3D Object(multipatch), Point Cloud, Integrated Mesh scene layers. You can also publish your own elevation layers to Online as well. The link posted above shows all supported layer types in scenes.